# Errors to Enable PSRemoting on win2008R2 and Win7

Tags: powershell

Today I need enable PSRemoting on W2008R2 and Win7:

All VMs are in workgroup.
I have setup same administrator account with same pwd on each VMs.
Run Enable-PSRemoting in powershell with administrator role.
However I still faced following errors:

Error 1:

> Set-WSManQuickConfig : Access is denied.

Error 2:

> [192.168.23.2] Connecting to remote server failed with the following
>   error message : The WinRM client cannot process th e request. If the
>   authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client
>   computer is not joined to a domain , then HTTPS transport must be used
>   or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts
>   configuration setting.  Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note
>   that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
>   You can get more information about that by running the following
>   command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken

Error 3:

> Set-WSManQuickConfig : WinRM firewall exception will not work since
>   one of the network connection types on this machine  is set to Public.
>   Change the network connection type to either Domain or Private and try
>   again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After google, error are fixed with following solution:

**Error 1:**
Set-WSManQuickConfig : Access is denied.

**Solution:**
Run following cmd with administrator role.

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

**Error 2:**

> If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the
>   client computer is not joined to a domain , then HTTPS transport must
>   be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts
>   configuration setting.

**Solution:**
Run following cmd on your client machine

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts *
```

**Error 3:**

> Set-WSManQuickConfig : WinRM firewall exception will not work since
>   one of the network connection types on this machine is set to Public.
>   Change the network connection type to either Domain or Private and try
>   again.

**Solution:**
ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/03/setting-network-location-to-private.aspx
Run following ps script with adminsitrator role:

```
#Skip network location setting for pre-Vista operating systems 
if([environment]::OSVersion.version.Major -lt 6) { return } 

#Skip network location setting if local machine is joined to a domain. 
if(1,3,4,5 -contains (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).DomainRole) { return } 

#Get network connections 
$networkListManager = [Activator]::CreateInstance([Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID([Guid]"{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}")) 
$connections = $networkListManager.GetNetworkConnections() 

#Set network location to Private for all networks 
$connections | % {$_.GetNetwork().SetCategory(1)}
```

Answer (score 6):

For error 3, run this command:

```
Set-WSManQuickConfig -SkipNetworkProfileCheck
```

When you connect your network, it gets set to Public, Private, or Domain. If the current profile is set to Public, `Set-WSManQuickConfig` will fail with that message. You can either change it (if the system will let you) or skip the profile check.

Comment: Parameter -SkipNetworkProfileCheck aviable in PowerShell version 3.0 or higher.